# Fluent API - setting an integer or smallint field to unsigned

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-fluent-api

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- Fluent API

When building the model itself, I can set a field to be unsigned by using the correct methods:

```
public ushort? NumberEmployees { get; set; }
```

This will give me values from 0 to 65,536 instead of -32768 to 32,767.

However, when I use Fluent API, I seem to be [limited by what kind of data types I can implement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187752.aspx) for the SQL table, at least where `.hascolumntype("")` is concerned. How can I implement an unsigned smallint through Fluent API?

So far, my Fluent API string for that particular field looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Property(x => x.NumberEmployees).HasColumnType("smallint").IsOptional();
```

but obviously a `smallint` is *not* the same as a `ushort`. And if I remove the `.HasColumnType("")` statement, migrations throw an error:

```
The property 'NumberEmployees' is not a declared property on type 'Company'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: The database doesn't know what a ushort is. It is a smallint for sql server. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c197e07-896d-4d82-8aac-5a37601926ec/sql-server-2008-compact-edition-what-type-we-should-use-for-ushort-systemuint16?forum=sqlce

Comment: here is a nice reference sheet of the types sql server knows (sorry if you are using a diff dbms, pls tag it)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No wonder I haven't been able to find a solution. So unsigned integer types are for safety within the code, but they would map to their wider versions in the DB, correct? The argument (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78918) makes sense, but it still sucks from a hearding-cats perspective when dealing with both code and DB, especially if you want your code data types to be implicitly incapable of negative numbers.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those disconnects. The type for classes versus the types for the DBMS of choice. Especially fun with dates.  =)

Comment: Personally, I match data types. The only reason to use ushort (for a field to store in DB) is for sanity for not less than 0, and its really easy to pop a validator in for that (decorate the model). It's actually better to put that sort of thing, which is business logic really, on the model anyway.

Comment: Actually, I haven't run into an issue with dates yet, perhaps since I explicitly create them as yyyy-MM-dd when adding to a `date` field in the DB. What issues have you run into?

Comment: Dates with no time portion stored as datetime coupled with timezones cause a lot of fun, especially when you have users (or a web server) in new york and the database is in illinois. A lot of our problems were solved by either using UTC times, or storing dates as strings, but then you have to format things or run into other problems caused by the solution. We had issues where the midnight on some date would cause it to roll an hour forward and changed the date effectively to the next day. (DataTable does some auto conversions)

Comment: Why not just store all dates as UTC and assign a time zone offset to each user? That way you can determine their local time without having to bugger with the dates themselves.